# Magento 2 Error while saving product

Tags: magento2, product, save

I am getting "

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to pass time string (17/06/2019) 
>   0(1):Unexpected character
>
> error while saving product.

See the Screen shot below [Image Here](https://prnt.sc/ojqhsb)

What can be the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: did you set the speical price from and to date ?

Answer (score 0):

try this fix 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18578/commits/88592facd5d34872ac2f2051dda246703091cacc

it worked for me in magento 2.2.6

if this not work
Try this Module:-
https://github.com/fernandofauth/magento2_datetime

Comment: I would like to add, this issue is seen at my clients end and not my end. When i do edits it works fine for me. but when my client try from their end, it gives such error. Do you feel its a code error?

Comment: When this error display.
add new product or edit product.

Comment: @Mahendra While editing.

Comment: @MahendraSingh any idea about this?